# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$start_clock' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/gabrydoc/public_html/fantacalcio/footer.php on line 4

Tags: php

I searched some similar thread but I cannot solve this issue in the code. I have php 5.4.

```
$start_time = $start_clock[1]   $start_clock[2];
```

Comment: Space not allowed in variable. What you trying so for

Comment: What do you want to do.?And how everybody know that you are trying to concatante two values without mentioning it in the question.?

Comment: Thank you very much but its not my code and i dont know it but its open source code and there is some little issue to fix. Now i solve my problems thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the sign between $start_clock[1] and $start_clock[2]:

```
 $start_time = $start_clock[1] + $start_clock[2];
```

or

```
 $start_time = $start_clock[1] - $start_clock[2];
```

or

```
 $start_time = $start_clock[1] . $start_clock[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the two variables using a **`.`**

Seems like you are trying to add a space between the two variables.. In that case .. do like this

```
$start_time = $start_clock[1]." ".$start_clock[2];
                       ------^ // Using the . Operator
```